# For Lechem Mishneh, can one of the challot remain in its package?

Tags: challah-shabbat-bread

Let's say someone wants to keep the second challah in its package to maintain its freshness for the next day. Can one have one challah out to be used and leave the second one in its package while saying the bracha?

Comment: This is an interesting question @DanF which I have considered before. I think this is dependent upon the type of package. If it is completely transparent so that you can see the second challah, I suspect that it is permissible. Think in terms of a related idea, making a blessing in the presence of excrement. If there is no smell and it is farther than four amot, it is only permissible when you cannot see it. Behind you or covered, OK. In your field of vision, prohibited.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Do you not fulfill Lechem Mishneh if you covered the bread with a Challah-cover during the blessing? That's the logical conclusion if comparing to Ervah